# How to change the value of innodb_lock_wait_timeout from hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql, innodb, rowlocking

We are using AWS Aurora 2.x database ( compatible with MySQL 5.7 ). From our application, we are interacting with database using hibernate. In one scenario, we want to use a custom value instead of the default one ( 50 seconds ).

I was able to change the value from MySQL work bench but not with Session/Transaction/Query class methods that belong to hibernate.

Comment: I consider 50 ridiculously high; I hope you are not trying to raise it.  If so, explain your application; maybe we can discuss a workaround.

Comment: Thank you James for looking into this. No we do not want to raise this. At application end, we want to set a less value like 10 seconds. We use Aurora Mysql database ( Compatible with MySQL 5.7 ) and in our application we use hibernate (version 3.x ) to connect with it.

Comment: Aurora may have a way to change the configuration.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the prompt reply. Yes. From Aurora end, we can update the lock wait time out. Are there no other ways can we do that from Hibernate end? Does hibernate 3.x do not support it for MySQL or no hibernate version supports these for MySQL?

Comment: Random clue:  sys.ps_setup_save

Comment: Hi Rick,
One observation: When the rows are locked for write operation, insert queries also waiting for the lock to release. We have not locked using primary key. May I know what's happening.

Comment: Connect as root and do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`.  It may provide more clues.